# Based on two matching columns, id like to sum the third based on match

Tags: excel

[enter image description here][1]
I am looking for some Excel help please...

I have 3 columns

```
|...A...|...B...|...C...|

  BAT.     BLK.     1

  BAT.     Blu.     2

  CAT.     Blk.     2

  BAT.     Blk.     2
```

in excel I have tried to figure out ( without success) how I can sum column c only when certain matches occur.
I am trying to figure out what formula I would need to select BAT+Blk and it sum up the matches...so in this instance the answer would be 3

Comment: Try looking into `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use SUMIFs for this. I've replicated your columns in A, B, and C.

Columns F & G are the criteria you want to use, and H3 is:

> =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,F3,B:B,G3)

You can copy it down for however many rows of criteria you have.